# Refactoring with generic and delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following code:

```
Type1 Method1(Type2 p)
{
    try
    {
        return DoSomething(p)
    }
    catch{ExceptionType1}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType2}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType3}
    {
    }
}

Type3 Method2(Type4 p)
{
    try
    {
        return DoSomethingElse(p)
    }
    catch{ExceptionType1}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType2}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType3}
    {
    }
}
```

How can i refactor this code to have something like:

```
TResult ExceptionalMethod(Methodx(T)){
    try
    {
        return Methodx(T);
    }
    catch{ExceptionType1}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType2}
    {
    }
    catch{ExceptionType3}
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Adrya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
TResult ExceptionalMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> methodx, T parameter){
   try
   {
      return methodx(parameter);
   }
   catch(ExceptionType1)
   {
   }
   catch(ExceptionType2)
   {
   }
   catch(ExceptionType3)
   {
   }

   return default(TResult);
}
```

I do hope you do something useful in those catches.

**EDIT**
If you don't have the `Func<T, TResult>` delegate in your version of the framework, you can easily add it, nothing special to it:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);
```

Comment: You need the input to apply the function to as well, and something to return if there are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, yes i do something with the exceptions. Could you please change the code to for 3.0 version of .net framework. Func was introduced only in 3.5.

Comment: @Adrya - added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want:

```
TResult ExceptionalMethod<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> func,
                                            TSource input)
{
    try
    {
        return func(input);
    }
    catch(ExceptionType1) {}
    catch(ExceptionType2) {}
    catch(ExceptionType3) {}
    return default(TResult);
}
```

However, you should also reconsider catching exceptions and swallowing them like this - does your real code do something useful with them, such as logging?

Note the return statement at the end - that may well be inappropriate, but if you're catching those exceptions, you'll have to return *something*.

Answer (score 0):

```
TResult ExceptionalMethod<TResult>(Action<T> action)){
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a full sample to do what you want using delegates and Func:

```
using System;

namespace GenericsDelegates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test1 = ExceptionalMethod(TestMethod1, "test");
            string test2 = ExceptionalMethod(TestMethod2, "test");

            Console.WriteLine(test1);
            Console.WriteLine(test2);
        }

        public static TResult ExceptionalMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func, T param)
        {
            return func(param);
        }

        public static string TestMethod1(string param)
        {
            return "TestMethod1-" + param;
        }

        public static string TestMethod2(string param)
        {
            return "TestMethod2-" + param;
        }
    }
}
```